# Make [npmjs] a synonym of [npm]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Make [npmjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npmjs) a synonym of [npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm). According to their excerpts, they're both about the package manager. I don't see a clear differences in the questions either.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the 53 questions tagged [npmjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npmjs), 36 already had the tag [npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm), and the excerpt made it abundantly clear that they both were the same:

> For issues relating to the npm package manager for JavaScript.

Alex O'Mara had proposed [npmjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npmjs) as a synonym for [npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm), Aug 27, shortly after this question, and it had received just one vote. I approved the synonym, in the direction: [npmjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npmjs) (x 53) → [npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/npm) (x 27802). I'll wait for a couple of days and then merge the tags.